# Problem with running demo webpart as part of 'Setting up your development environment' tutorial

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am following [Setting up your development environment](https://youtu.be/-2-jWsEa2Yw). When I run **gulp serve** it launches browser with `https://localhost:5432/workbench` url and shows error `'This site can't be reached'` and error `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

It might be related to self signed certificate being used.
I noticed that when I ran gulp **trust-dev-cert** it went through without any error, but I did not get a Security alert to accept the certificate.

- nodejs: v10.24.0
- npm:    6.14.11

Comment: Could it be that the 5432 port is taken by someone? What if you chagne the part in the `serve.json` file from 5432 to 5433 and try again?

Comment: I change to 5433, but the issue persists.

Comment: Actually it works! Initially I only change port in initialPage property. There is another property to change - 'port'. Now when I change its value to 5433 as well it starts working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when using local workbench:

Open **serve.json** file and replace 5432 port with 5433 like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://localhost:5433/workbench",
  "api": {
    "port":5433 ,
    "entryPath": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench/lib/api/"
  }
}
```

Don't forget to update the port for the `initialPage` as well.